# How to find third values comparing two values in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Here I have two arrays array1 and array2 I want to find ids from array1 which array1's names matched with array2 values how to find ids in javascript ?

array1:

```
[ {id: 1, name: "Hindi"}
  {id: 2, name: "English"}
  {id: 3, name: "French"}
  {id: 4, name: "Russian"}
  {id: 5, name: "Urdu"}
  {id: 6, name: "Japanese"}
]
```

array2:

```
["Hindi", "Russian", "Urdu"]
```

I tried this code

```
console.log(array1.find(x => x.name === array2).id;
```

Comment: What would you expect from e.g. `"Hindi" === ["Hindi", "Russian", "Urdu"]`? Look into filtering and mapping arrays.

Comment: Do you expect an *array* of id values as output?

Comment: @jonrsharpe no "Hindi" === "Hindi" , "Russian" === "Russian", "Urdu" === "Urdu" and want that ids in array like this [1, 4, 5]

Comment: That is **not** what you've written. Try decomposing this into smaller steps, e.g. how to check whether a given value is *in* (not *equal to*) an array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simplest code for array intersection in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get objects whose names are in the array.Then use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to convert array of values to array of ids.

In your code you are comparing the string with array `x.name === array2`. You should use `includes()`

```js
let arr = [ {id: 1, name: "Hindi"}, {id: 2, name: "English"}, {id: 3, name: "French"}, {id: 4, name: "Russian"}, {id: 5, name: "Urdu"}, {id: 6, name: "Japanese"} ]
let lang = ["Hindi", "Russian", "Urdu"];

let res = arr.filter(x => lang.includes(x.name)).map(x => x.id);
console.log(res)
```

Comment: @DDD Consider accepting the answer if it works for you. I don't know why I got a downvote eventhough the code works according to need of OP.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `filter` method in combination with `map` and *destructuring*

```js
let arr1 = [ {id: 1, name: "Hindi"}, {id: 2, name: "English"}, {id: 3, name: "French"}, {id: 4, name: "Russian"}, {id: 5, name: "Urdu"}, {id: 6, name: "Japanese"} ], arr2 = ["Hindi", "Russian", "Urdu"];

console.log(arr1.filter(({name}) => arr2.includes(name)).map(({id}) => id));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
 var a = [{
      id: 1,
      name: "Hindi"
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: "English"
    }, {
      id: 3,
      name: "French"
    }, {
      id: 4,
      name: "Russian"
    }, {
      id: 5,
      name: "Urdu"
    }, {
      id: 6,
      name: "Japanese"
    }]
    var b = ["Hindi", "Russian", "Urdu"];
    var c = a.filter(function(i){
    return b.indexOf(i.name)>-1;
    });
    console.log(c); // New Array with filtered values
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work too :)

```js
var a1 = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "Hindi"
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: "English"
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: "French"
}, {
  id: 4,
  name: "Russian"
}, {
  id: 5,
  name: "Urdu"
}, {
  id: 6,
  name: "Japanese"
}]
var a2 = ["Hindi", "Russian", "Urdu"];
var filter = a1.filter(function(i) {
  return a2.indexOf(i.name) > -1;
}).map(function(obj) {
  return obj.id;
});;
console.log(filter);
```